# JQuery AJAX POST calls fails in IE9

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, internet-explorer-9, cross-domain

I'm using jquery ajax calls to call the web services, which are placed on a different domain. It was working fine in all the browsers except Internet Explorer 9.

I've used jquery 'XDomainRequest.js' for IE9 cross domain ajax. Using this, my ajax calls are working in IE but not the calls with method 'POST'. The data is always passed as null. Below is my ajax call which I'm using:

```
function generateJSON(URL, data, method, onSuccessFunc)
{
$.ajax
        ({      
            type:method,
            cache:false,
            url:URL,
            dataType:"json",
            data: data,
            success : function(json){ onSuccessFunc(json); },
            error : function(){ errorFunc() }
        });
}
```

Please suggest What should I do to make my 'cross domain POST AJAX' calls to work in IE9.

Comment: What do you mean "the data is always passed as null"?  How have you come to this conclusion exactly?

Comment: say for example, I'm calling my 'login_authenticate' web service.. it takes Email and Password as parameters... The IE debugger shows the data correctly in 'Request Body', but I'm getting the same result in 'Response Body' as I get when I pass null in parameters.. Changing the parameters doesn't affect the response at all

Comment: Still not following you.  Are you simply having trouble recovering the request payload server side?

Comment: Recently found something that.. IE9 only allows text/plain data to be sent in cors ajax post calls.. I'm sending JSON data.. If its true, please tell me some workaround for this

Comment: Please see my last question/ comment.  You can send any data you like, you just can't set the Content-Type of the request, so your server framework will not be able to automatically parse the request payload for you.

Comment: I'm sending json data.. and everything is working fine with other browsers like chrome, safari, mozilla, opera... Even with IE10 and IE11... So, sending and receiving data at server is not a trouble..

Comment: The issue you are experiencing is detailed in my previous comment.  This is specific to IE9 and IE8.

Comment: Is there any workaround ? without modifying anything on server side..